# Cannot get biblatex' 21-indexing-advanced.tex to build

Tags: biblatex

I'm on Texlive 2011 on Linux, and I try to run this example:

ftp://www.ctan.org/ctan/macros/latex2e/exptl/biblatex/doc/examples/21-indexing-advanced.tex

I build, as recommended, with:

```
latex 21-indexing-advanced.tex
bibtex 21-indexing-advanced
latex 21-indexing-advanced.tex
```

On the second pass, I get this:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \l@german 
l.137 \raggedright

?
```

Apparently, something is missing there, but I cannot tell what. Any help with this?

---

EDIT: The link may be old, but that is the same example which is included in current `biblatex` in TexLive 2011:

```
$ MYLOCFILE=$(find /path/to/texlive/ -name 21-indexing-advanced.tex)
$ echo $MYLOCFILE
/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/doc/latex/biblatex/examples/21-indexing-advanced.tex
$ wget ftp://www.ctan.org/ctan/macros/latex2e/exptl/biblatex/doc/examples/21-indexing-advanced.tex
 ...

$ diff $MYLOCFILE ./21-indexing-advanced.tex
$ # nothing is output => they are identical ...
```

Logfile - first pass:

```
$ pdflatex 21-indexing-advanced.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./21-indexing-advanced.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, lo
aded.
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/english.ldf
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def)))
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.sty
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty))
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.def)
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.cfg))
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/authortitle.b
bx
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx)
)
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/authortitle.c
bx) (/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg)
) (/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/index/index.sty

LaTeX Warning: Command \markboth  has changed.
               Check if current package is valid.


LaTeX Warning: Command \markright  has changed.
               Check if current package is valid.

)
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/american.lbx
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx))

No file 21-indexing-advanced.aux.
No file 21-indexing-advanced.bbl.
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1cmtt.fd)

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'piccato' on page 1 undefined on input line 127.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'gaonkar' on page 1 undefined on input line 127.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'malinowski' on page 1 undefined on input line 127.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'coleridge' on page 1 undefined on input line 127.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'gerhardt' on page 1 undefined on input line 127.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'cicero' on page 1 undefined on input line 127.

[1{/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}
]

LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 135.

No file 21-indexing-advanced.ind.
No file 21-indexing-advanced.nnd.
No file 21-indexing-advanced.tnd.
(./21-indexing-advanced.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run BibTeX on the file(s):
(biblatex)                21-indexing-advanced
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

 ) <~/.texlive2011/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ecrm
1000.600pk> <~/.texlive2011/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappe
n/ec/ecbx1000.600pk> <~/.texlive2011/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfou
r/jknappen/ec/ectt1440.600pk> <~/.texlive2011/texmf-var/fonts
/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ecbx1440.600pk>
Output written on 21-indexing-advanced.pdf (1 page, 12739 bytes).
Transcript written on 21-indexing-advanced.log.
```

.. then `bibtex 21-indexing-advanced` -- then second pass:

```
$ pdflatex 21-indexing-advanced.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./21-indexing-advanced.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, lo
aded.
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/english.ldf
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def)))
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.sty
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty))
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.def)
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.cfg))
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/authortitle.b
bx
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx)
)
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/authortitle.c
bx) (/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg)
) (/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/index/index.sty

LaTeX Warning: Command \markboth  has changed.
               Check if current package is valid.


LaTeX Warning: Command \markright  has changed.
               Check if current package is valid.

)
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/american.lbx
(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx))
 (./21-indexing-advanced.aux) (./21-indexing-advanced.bbl)

Package biblatex Warning: backend=biber required by .bib file.
(biblatex)                Some features may not work properly.

(/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1cmtt.fd) [1{/path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
Overfull \hbox (18.58575pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 137--137
\T1/cmr/m/n/10 (1961), pp. 579^^U588[][]; Wein-berg, Steven. ^^P  A Model of Le
p-tons.^^Q In: \T1/cmr/m/it/10 Phys. Rev. Lett.

Overfull \hbox (15.22781pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 137--137
\T1/cmr/m/n/10 rated Pd-N-heterocyclic car-benes in Mizoroki-Heck re-ac-tions.^
^Q In: \T1/cmr/m/it/10 J. Organomet.
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \l@german 
l.137 \raggedright

?
```

Comment: Can you add the first lines of the `.log` file? From `LaTeX2e` to `Document Class`

Comment: That's a very old link for `biblatex`. You really should use material from the release version.

Comment: Many thanks for the comments; @egreg - edited post now has logs from both runs; @JosephWright - that file is identical with the example included with current `biblatex` in TexLive 2011, see post edit.. Cheers!

Comment: I can only suspect that you have old auxiliary files or similar around. I have no issues with the file when I use the latest `biblatex`.

Comment: Thanks for reporting, @JosephWright - I'll re-try the example as soon as I get some time, and report back again...

Answer (score 4):

The example loads `biblatex` with the option setting `babel=hyphen` and issues `\nocite{*}`. So the bibliography hyphenates each entry in `biblatex-examples.bib` under the patterns indicated in the `hyphenation` field. The error

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \l@german
```

occurs because at least one entry has `hyphenation = {german}` and you don't have [German hyphenation patterns](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gnhyph) installed. The next release will issue a warning instead:

```
Package biblatex Warning: No hyphenation patterns for 'german'
```

The example has also been improved to avoid the `\markboth`/`\markright` warning messages that also appear in your log file.